# Dynamic conversion rows to columns SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have got a JOIN between transactions and Cards, simplified it looks like this:

```
TranID  Date                    Card        ShopType    ShopName
11      2018-01-25 15:45:29.000 119317903   S           ShopA
12      2018-01-25 16:31:01.000 119317903   S           ShopB
13      2018-01-25 13:39:08.000 119325674   G           ShopC
14      2018-01-25 15:43:35.000 119325674   S           ShopA
15      2018-01-25 16:31:15.000 119325674   S           ShopD
```

I want to create a new table with one row per card, including all transactions and details of that card. Number of transactions can vary. So desired result would be:

```
Card    TranID_1    Date_1  ShopType_1  ShopName_1  TranID_2    Date_2 ShopType_2   ShopName_2  TranID_3    Date_3  ShopType_3  ShopName_3
119317903   11      2018-01-25 15:45:29.000 S       ShopA   12  2018-01-25 16:31:01.000 S   ShopB               
119325674   13      2018-01-25 13:39:08.000 G       ShopC   14  2018-01-25 15:43:35.000 S   ShopA   15  2018-01-25 16:31:15.000 S   ShopD
```

I Found this on SO, but I can't quite get the dynamic SQL syntax to work for me. (dynamic SQL always gets the better of me).

[Efficiently convert rows to columns in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by executing a dynamic sql query.

**Query**

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

select @sql = 'select [Card], ' + stuff((
        select distinct 
        ',min(case [sl_no] when ' + cast([sl_no] as varchar(100)) 
        + ' then [TranID] end) as [TranID_' + cast([sl_no] as varchar(100)) + ']' +
        ',min(case [sl_no] when ' + cast([sl_no] as varchar(100)) 
        + ' then [Date] end) as [Date_' + cast([sl_no] as varchar(100)) + ']' +
        ',min(case [sl_no] when ' + cast([sl_no] as varchar(100)) 
        + ' then [ShopType] end) as [ShopType_' + cast([sl_no] as varchar(100)) + ']' +
        ',min(case [sl_no] when ' + cast([sl_no] as varchar(100)) 
        + ' then [ShopName] end) as [ShopName_' + cast([sl_no] as varchar(100)) + ']' 
        from (
            select [sl_no] = row_number() over(
                partition by [Card] 
                order by [Date]
            ), * from [dbo].[tbl_name]
        ) as [t]
        for xml path('')
    )
    , 1, 1, ''
);

set @sql += ' from (select [sl_no] = row_number() over(partition by [Card] order by [Date]), 
            * from [dbo].[tbl_name]) as [t] group by [Card];';

exec(@sql);
```

Comment: Exactly why I posted this. I could not have achieved this myself. Syntax seems so complex to me. Thanks a lot @Wanderer, this indeed works!

Comment: Just one more quick question, probably over-asking here...  :) I want to create a new table, so I would like to select this into a Table. I've tried several places, but have not succeeded. Where do I put the results table?

Comment: Yeah (even) I get that. But where: set@sql += 'into #Results' OR in the dynamic statement itself. Probably self explainatory for you, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @SQL_M : if you are creating temp table using dynamic sql query, then that temp table will not be available out of the dynamic sql query.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out, finally: SET @Sql += ' INTO ##T'  works.