# How do I combine two columns into single column in static / dynamic pivot query using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a schema like this

demo(month_year(navarchar), datecount(int), destination(nvarchar), type(nvarchar)).

In output i want to transform the rows to columns with concatenate columns.

```
datecount  |  Month_year   | destination   type  
-------------------------+---------------+-------------------
07         | March - 18    | ABC          No
23         | August - 2018 | ABC          No
29         | August - 2018 | XYZ          Sold Out 
04         | July - 2018   | PQR          Sold Out
10         | July - 2018   | XYZ          No
25         | July - 2018   | ABC          Sold Out
```

In the output i want,

```
Month_Year      1                 2                 3 ...     
July - 2018     04(Sold Out-PQR)  10(No-XYZ)        25(Sold Out-ABC)
August - 2018   23(No-ABC)        29(Sold Out-XYZ)
```

I have tried more using the PIVOTE function. Facing the problem to display combination of datecount with destination and type as per above expected output. But could not get the solution. Please help me.

Comment: Do you have fixed column number in output?

Comment: The column number depends on the dates of each month. Usually i want static query for the output,

Comment: Seems like a similar problem to what I recently had: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51166622/dynamic-conversion-rows-to-columns-sql

Comment: @SQL_M : looking for combine 3 columns and show output in single column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate the values before pivoting.

```
;WITH ToPivot AS
(
    SELECT
        D.month_year,
        ConcatenatedValues = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), D.datecount) + '(' + D.type + '-' + D.destination + ')',
        NumberToPivot = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY D.month_year ORDER BY D.datecount ASC)
    FROM
        Demo AS D
)
SELECT
    P.*
FROM
    ToPivot AS T
    PIVOT (
        MAX(T.ConcatenatedValues)
        FOR T.NumberToPivot IN (
            [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], 
            [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], 
            [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], 
            [29], [30], [31])
    ) AS P
```

Comment: Superbb..!!! Exactly why I posted this. I could not have achieved this myself. Thanks a lot @EzLo, this indeed works!